# android - how to get location of sytem audio

Tags: java, android, system

right now, I'm avoiding loading system audio for the devices and emulator *I have* by hardcoding them in SQLite `NOT LIKE ...` statements while querying the `ContentResolver`, but, what I have found that the location for the storage of sytem audio(like alarm tones and all the audio factory loaded) doesn't have a standard location in all android device.

So, to avoid loading all system audio, I need a way to fetch the directory where these audio are located, so far, I have gathered a data of these locations where the sytem audio might be:

```
"/system%",
"/storage/emulated/legacy/Ringtones/%",
"/storage/emulated/0/Ringtones%",
"/product/media/audio%"
```

but, since these might not be adequate, is there a way to fetch the directory path where the system audio is located in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query audio files with [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) , then filter audio files with [AudioColumns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns) , and more specific for alarm sounds use [IS_ALARM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns#IS_ALARM).

As you say :

> I have found that the location for the storage of sytem audio doesn't have a standard location in all android device.

MediaStore is a database which holds references of the files and it is a solution to query files in different system storage locations.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, it has given me some ideas, but if you can, then could you please post a little snippet of code of how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
String[] mProjection =
                {
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,       # path
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM,   
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,   
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE
                };
Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                mProjection,
                null,
                null);
```

> Note: for external storage use: MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

```
int index_data = mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

if (mCursor != null) {
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {

        // Gets the value from the column.
        newData = mCursor.getString(index_data);

        // Insert code here to process the retrieved data.

        // end of while loop
    }
} else {

    // Insert code here to report an error if the cursor is null or the provider threw an exception.
}
```

**References:**

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics#java

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64539937/3541319

Comment: the internal storage media location seem to different from storage location for system audio

Answer (score 1):

Code to List all alarms in fragment:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED
        )

        val audio: Uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

        val cur = context.contentResolver.query(
            audio,
            projection,  // Which columns to return
            "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM}>0",  // Which rows to return (all rows)
            null,  // Selection arguments (none)
            null // Ordering
        ) ?: return

        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {

            val displayNameColumn: Int = cur.getColumnIndex(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
            )
            val dateColumn: Int = cur.getColumnIndex(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED
            )
            do {
                val displayName = cur.getString(displayNameColumn)
                val date = cur.getString(dateColumn)

                Log.i(
                    "Listing Alarms",
                    " displayName=$displayName , date=$date"
                )
            } while (cur.moveToNext())
        }
```

You need to add
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`